# Not getting result from php in ajax codeigniter.?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here is my little code of ajax and php, Which I want pass and get for login system.

Here I have ajax code.

```
 <script>
    $("input#login_btn").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

            var x = document.forms["loginform"]["login_username"].value;
            var x1 = document.forms["loginform"]["login_password"].value;
            var y = document.getElementById('login-error');
            var z = document.getElementById('password-error');

            if (x == "") { y.style.display ='block'; }else{ y.style.display ='none'; }
            if (x1 == "") { z.style.display ='block'; }else{ z.style.display ='none'; } 

                var d = document.forms["loginform"]["login_username"].value;
                var d1 = document.forms["loginform"]["login_password"].value;                       

            if(d != '' && d1 != ''){
                $.ajax({
                   url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Auth",
                   type: "POST",
                   data:{login_username: $('input#login_username').val(), login_password: $('input#login_password').val()},

                   success : function(data){                                                    
                        if(data.success == "true"){
                            var url = $('#current_loginurl').val();                 
                            window.location.href=url;                       
                        }else{
                            $('#loginform')[0].reset();
                            $("#login_fail").show('fast');
                        }
                   },
                   error : function(data){                      
                        $('#loginform')[0].reset();
                        $("#login_fail").show('fast');
                   }

                });
            }   
        });
</script>
```

And here is my PHP code in codeigniter. I am using myslqi in codeigniter.

```
public function index(){
            require_once('connect.php');

                $url =  $this->input->post('current_loginurl');
                $username =  $this->input->post('login_username');
                $password =  $this->input->post('login_password');              

                $qry = mysqli_query($con ,"select * from `user_profile` where E_Id = '".$username."'") or die(mysqli_error($con));                  
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
                $data = mysqli_num_rows($qry);

                if(!empty($data) && $data >0){

                    $session = array(
                            'client_username' => $row['F_Name']." ".$row['L_Name']
                              );


                    $this->session->set_userdata($session);
                    $datas = array(
                        'success' => true
                    );                  
                    echo json_encode($datas);
                    //redirect($url);
                    return true;

                }else{
                    $datas = array(
                        'success' => false
                    );                  
                    echo json_encode($datas);
                    return false;
                }                   

        }
```

I did lost of alter in this code but can't get success. any one can help where am I wrong. How can I get return result in ajax.

Comment: Are you using csrf token for form submiting??

Comment: check your browser console and see

Comment: what's the error with your code? what's the output you are getting ?

Comment: You're wide open to SQL injections. Why are you using your own DB-code if your using CodeIgniter?

Comment: Iknow that but first I want to get it working.

Comment: You should start by making your code safe. Otherwise when you get this working, you still need to rewrite it and you might end up creating new bugs. Better to do it correctly from the start. Who knows, your issue might even resolve it self by doing that.

Comment: use `dataType: 'json'` in `$.ajax` options. and remove `return` from php.

Comment: @Gaurav i do that and also I change `success => true` to  `success => 'true'` and also do same with false. and now working thanks for help

Comment: @Mahi then use like this: `if(data.success){}`. Also check what are you getting in ajax response `data`

Comment: remove return true and return false after echo json_ecode, why you don't use codeigniter active record ? queries in codeigniter don't write like this

Comment: in your browser console check your network tab -> the output in the response.

Answer (score 0):

**When CSRF is enabled we need to submit it with the post data:**

```
data: {
      csrf_token_name: CONFIG.csrf_cookie_name
}
```

CONFIG is created in a CI view file (.php) and loaded in with your controller or templating system:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var CONFIG = {
            'base_url': '<?php echo base_url(); ?>',
            'csrf_token_name' : "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>",
            'csrf_cookie_name' : "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>"
        }
</script>
```

**REMARK: when CSRF regeneration is on (config.php) the second time you make the call it will give an error 403** (check the network tab in your browser console). Either turn off CSRF regeneration for the whole application
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/why-refresh-csrf-token-per-form-request

or do it for just those methods you use for ajax by adding this in the CSRF section in config.php around line 435 (below `$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;`):

```
$no_regen = array(
    '(HMVC-module/)controller/method'
);

if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    foreach ($no_regen as $csrf_page){
        if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $csrf_page) !== FALSE) {
            $config['csrf_regenerate'] = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus remark: please validate your POST data.